# How in Laravel to get all records from "articles" table that do not have a category?

Tags: database, laravel, model, left-join, relationship

The database has three tables:

- "articles" -> "id (int), title(varchar)",
- "categories" -> "id (int), title(varchar)" and
- "categoryables" -> "category_id (int), categoryable_id (int),
  categoryable_type(varchar)".

I also have two models for working with these "Articles" and "Categories" tables, and I don't have a "categoryable" model

I get all categories related to a specific article using many-to-many polymorphic relationships from the "Article" model:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categoryable');
}
```

From this I conclude that Laravel itself creates a "categoryable" model and a relationship called "categoryable".

Also, I can get all articles belonging to a specific category using the relationship "articles()" from "Category" model:

```
public function articles(){
    return $this->morphedByMany(Article::class, 'categoryable');
}
```

But I also have articles that do not belong to any category.

How can I get articles that do not belong to any category?

Comment: It seems you would have to get them from the Articles table directly, as not having a catagory means they won't be in the pivot table. Might it work for you to get all Articles, then make a new array and map over the result of the getArticles query, that returned all of the Articles, and anywhere that catagory=null (or empty, or whatever) set it to 'Uncatagorised' in the new array? Then you could just return that new array, as all Articles would now have some form of catagory, even if it's just 'Uncatagorised'.

Comment: @user6854465 It is a good idea to create pivot table entries for all articles, even those without a category.
Please tell me how to realization this, if I want to add a NULL value in the "category_id" field, if necessary to the "categoryables" table, when creating, updating and deleting a record from the article model?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by  query with join, if someone needs it, I post my solution.

Since I need the data to build the menu, that is, on all pages of the site, I decided to create a service provider "MenuServiceProvider" so that I do not ask the same query in the controller every time.

In the service provider, I created the following method and query with a Left Join:

// Articles without categories

```
public function articles_without_category(){
    View::composer('site.category', function ($view){
        $articles_without_category = Article::leftJoin('categoryables', function ($joun){
            $joun->on('articles.id', '=', 'categoryables.categoryable_id')
                ->whereNull('categoryable_id');
        })->where('published', 1)->paginate(10);
        $view->with([
            'category' => Category::where('slug', 'like', '%without-category%')->first(),
            'articles' => $articles_without_category,
        ]);
    });
}
```

This query is called in the Boot method of the MenuServiceProvider as follows:

```
public function boot(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->is('category/without-category*')){
        $this->articles_without_category();
    }
}
```